# Como passar item selecionado entre Activities

Tags: java, android

No momento, estou com dúvida de fazer com que o item clicado nessa tela

http://prntscr.com/eyjdzo

apareça selecionado nessa tela

http://prntscr.com/eyjecw

Comment: Você chegou a iniciar algum código? Tente começar a fazer, e se tiver alguma dificuldade vc posta aqui, É muita coisa pra ensinar a fazer desde o começo

Comment: Posta seus códigos para que possamos ajudar melhor.